# Client REST processar response em JSON sem conhecer objetos de domínio

Tags: java, json, restful

estou fazendo um servidor RESTFull com o Spring MVC, o controller só retorna JSON, até ai blz, teria como o meu client não conhecer nada das classes de domínio e mesmo assim processar as requisições?

Eu estava pensando em transformar o JSON em um objeto como se fosse uma tabela de banco de dados, dai dava para manipular os dados, como colunas e valores.

O fato é que eu não quero que meu client conheça nenhuma classe de domínio, ele apenas receba as informações, processe, e mostre ao usuário, o usuário faz as devidas alterações e envia.

Eu criei uma classe chamada DataSet, o objetivo é manipular dados como se fosse uma tabela de forma genérica.

exemplo

```
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

    //Pode importar a partir de um pojo
    /*dataset.fromPOJO(customerObject);
    dataset.fromJSON(JSONString);
    dataset.fromCSV(CSV);*/

    dataset.setDataSource(datasource);
    dataset.setTableName("Clientes");
    dataset.setLimit(100);
    dataset.setFetchRows(100);

    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("Nome", FieldType.STRING, 100) );
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("DataNascimento", FieldType.DATE));
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("DataHoraCadastro", FieldType.DATETIME));
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("Foto", FieldType.BINARY));
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("Credito", FieldType.DOUBLE, 2));
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("Vendedor", FieldType.LOOKUP, "TABELA_PESSOA", new String[]{"id"}, new String[]{"id_vendedor"}));
    dataset.getFields().add(new Field("Contatos", FieldType.DETAIL, "PESSOA_CONTATO", new String[]{"pessoa_id"}, new String[]{"id"} ));


    //Adicionando registro
    dataset.append();       
    dataset.getField("Nome").setValue("RODRIGO RODRIGUES DA COSTA");
    dataset.getField("DataNascimento").setValue("06/04/1985");
    dataset.getField("Credito").setValue(1765.87);      
    dataset.post();

    dataset.append();
    dataset.getField("Nome").setValue("MARIA CECILIA CABRAL RODRIGUES");
    dataset.getField("DataNascimento").setValue("11/03/2011");
    dataset.getField("Credito").setValue(333);      
    dataset.post();

    System.out.println("Mostrando uma quanitdade de "+dataset.getRecordCount() );
    //Monstrando todos os registros
    for (Record record : dataset.getRecords()) {
        System.out.println("Registro número "+record.getIndex() );
        System.out.println(record.getField("Nome").getValue() );
        System.out.println(record.getField("DataNascimento").getValue() );
    }
```

Pergunto, tem outra forma de fazer isso? Eu não quero que meu client saiba da existência das classe de domínio, dessa forma com o DataSet na minha visão dá certo, agora tem outra forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vamos simplificar?

Por que você não aplica o conceito do KISS? Keep It Simple Stupid! Eu sempre tento aplicar isso aos meu projetos.

Se você não quer expor suas classes de domínios por que você não faz algo como:

```
public class AtualizarClienteVO{
    String nome;
    Date aniversario;
    // etc
}
```

E no seu domínio você teria:

```
public class Pessoa{
    String nome;
    Date aniversario;
    // etc
}
```

Bastaria fazer depois pessoa.setNome(atualizarClienteVO.getNome()) e pronto. Seu modelo está protegido.

### Isso é boa prática?

É uma prática comum você ter um objeto que servirá apenas para levar os dados (geralmente conhecidos como VO, DTO). Ao mesmo tempo você mantém o seu domínio escondido.

Não tente algo complexo demais onde você teria pouco ganho. [=

Do modo acima você estaria mapeando apenas os dados da tela para um objeto qualquer e depois você faz o parse para o seu modelo.

### Conclusão

Eu vejo essa abordagem como boa prática pois:

1. Você manterá seu domínio/VIEW desacoplados. Eu já tive bastante experiência entre realizar alteração no domínio e não precisar alterar os VOs
2. Você poderá reutilizar os objetos de View em outros projetos. Caso você venha a ter outra view, ela poderá configurar coisas específicas apenas da view nos VOS, não afetará seu domínio
3. Criar um tipo bizarro de entidade para proteger o seu domínio apenas trará mais dificuldade de manutenção depois. Deixe suas classes com nomes fáceis de se ler e também fáceis de usar.

Comment: As classes VO seria uma representação do meu modelo (apenas os tributos) das classes de domínio lá no server, porém somente para o lado cliente? Inicialmente ela seria uma copy/past dos domínios? Se eu adicionar um atributo no domínio, teria que adicionar também no VO certo?

Comment: Vale salientar que o que eu postei é apenas para mostrar como seria atribuída as informações, porém, essa atribuição seria em runtime e de forma dinâmica, concordo que teria um pouco de trabalho para passar para a view.Exemplo, na tela de cliente, receberia a resposta em JSON, populava esse objeto automaticamente e mostraria em um grid por exemplo. Eu não precisaria criar nenhuma classe concreta para representar os dados, já que o lado cliente a única responsabilidade é, receber dados, manipular e enviar... Utilizando o VO, eu ainda consigo saber algo algo do domínio, ainda estou em dúvida...

Comment: Você pode ter 15 atributos no domínio e apenas 5 em um VO. Eles não precisam ser interligados. Cuidado para não fazer tudo "automático" e depois piorar e muito a manutenção do projeto. Exitem frameworks que já fazem esse populamento de um lado para o outro, uma coisa simples que até você poderia fazer e não ficaria complicado.

Comment: Entendi, realmente é difícil sem a classe que representa os dados no lado cliente, nesse caso fica mais fácil para fazer o parse do JSON para meus objetos. Eu sou leitor dos seus dois livros, JPA Eficaz e JSF, confesso que só uso hoje o JPA pois irei trabalhar com o Vaadin ao invés de JSF, parabéns pelos livros, muito prático e vai direto aos assuntos.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela força! =D